# Expression<Func> method gives convertion error when used in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, delegates

I know there are lots of similar questions about this, but I could not find my answer among them.

My function is like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<DateTime, DateTime?, DateTimeOffset>> GetDTOFromLocalAndUTC(DateTime localTime, DateTime? utcTime)
{
    int documentDateOffset = 0;
    DateTimeOffset result;

    if (utcTime.HasValue)
    {
        documentDateOffset = ((TimeSpan)(localTime - utcTime.Value)).Hours;
    }

    result = new DateTimeOffset(localTime, TimeSpan.FromHours(documentDateOffset));

    return (a, b) => result;
}
```

And my linq query is like this:

```
var q = from a in context.MyDBEntity
        where {some condition}
        select new MyDomainClass 
        {
            DocumentDateInDateTimeOffsetFormat = GetDTOFromLocalAndUTC(a.LocalDocumentDate, a.UTCDocumentDate)
        };
```

But it gives convertion error.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it that way...

```
public static DateTimeOffset GetDTOFromLocalAndUTC(DateTime localTime, DateTime? utcTime)
{
    int documentDateOffset = 0;
    DateTimeOffset result;

    if (utcTime.HasValue)
    {
        documentDateOffset = ((TimeSpan)(localTime - utcTime.Value)).Hours;
    }

    result = new DateTimeOffset(localTime, TimeSpan.FromHours(documentDateOffset));
    return result;
}
```

and then

```
var q = (from a in context.MyDBEntity
         where {some condition}
         select new 
         {
             a.LocalDocumentDate, 
             a.UTCDocumentDate
         })
         .AsEnumerable()
         .Select(a => new MyDomainClass 
         {
             DocumentDateInDateTimeOffsetFormat = GetDTOFromLocalAndUTC(a.LocalDocumentDate, a.UTCDocumentDate)
         });
```

First you select the two fields you need, then *locally* (`AsEnumerable()`) you call your function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want to use that trick. Because "AsEnumerable" causes the query to be executed immediately. For performance reasons I don't want an early db execution.

Comment: @caisenm No, it doesn't. Try it. Only enumerating the `IEnumerable<>`/`IQueryable<>` causes its execution

Comment: I've tried it. When I marked it as AsEnumerable it pulled the whole data. And made the joins in memory.

Comment: So you have other code *after* the `AsEnumerable()`, because I don't see any join in the posted code. Yes, everything *after* the `AsEnumerable()` will be executed locally. You can't say "execute this locally, but after this, I want to add something else that must be executed on the server". Everything that goes on the server must go first, everything that goes locally must go last.